# Error 401 While selecting fusion table using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-fusion-tables

Following is my code to select rows from fusion table. I am having error 401 in response of this i.e. authorization required. How to do so?  I couldnt find enough to add it or may be  i am not getting it :/ 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fusion Tables Layer Example: Basic JSONP Request</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
        width: 600px;
      }

      .store-name {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

      .address, .delivers {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM " +
            '15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw';
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
        // Construct the URL
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=' + encodedQuery + '&key=AIzaSyC41SwODXKVFnY4UrgeRwYZk1Ah_7eLgkw';
        console.log(url);
        // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          type: 'GET',
          Authorization : 'Basic MTBiaXR0ZmF0aW1hQHNlZWNzLmVkdS5wazp0QHl5YkA5Mg==',
          success: function (data) {
          alert('in success function ');
            var rows = data['rows'];
            var ftData = document.getElementById('ft-data');
                console.log(data);
          }
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<button onclick="initialize();">Authorize</button>
    <div id="ft-data"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Response returned :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: did you get any solution for it as i am facing same problem

Comment: No! i didnt get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is private that's why you are getting this just go to the table and click on share button then change the "who has access to anyone with the link can view"

Comment: btw Thanks a lot for the solution! :)

Comment: then try to change it to public